# Creating an INSERT TRIGGER that updates CreatedBy and UpdatedBy without firing the UPDATE TRIGGER on same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am trying to create an INSERT TRIGGER and UPDATE TRIGGER on all tables in my database that manage CreatedBy and UpdatedBy fields.

The problem that I am running into is that the following is in my INSERT trigger:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET CreatedBy = INSERTED.CreatedBy, 
    InsertDate = GetDate(), 
    UpdatedBy = INSERTED.UpdatedBy, 
    UpdateDate = GetDate() 
FROM INSERTED 
WHERE MyTable.Id = INSERTED.Id
```

The problem is that this UPDATE statement is additionally triggering the UPDATE trigger. I can not have this happen. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Is this the insert trigger on MyTable?

Comment: Please provide complete definition of you trigger

Comment: Yes MyTable is the table the trigger is being ran on. The problem is that the insert trigger uses an update statement to set the createdby and updatedby fields. This was firing the update trigger. I needed to avoid this from happening. Please see the answer I posted and let me know if you guys have any better solutions!

Comment: Why do you need to update the table you are inserting into with the values being inserted? I would also make the argument that you shouldn't be setting the Updated columns in an insert, this is an insert not an update. Why not make those columns not null with a default of getdate(). Or create an instead of trigger instead of updating the table right after you insert into it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a built in SQL function called IF  TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL().

I was able to wrap the update trigger with the following to prevent the update trigger from running when the insert trigger runs:

```
IF  TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() < 2
  --Trigger script here
END
```